# Django views accessible in the admin site

Tags: django, django-views, django-admin

I would like to embed front end views in my django admin site at any possible specified locale, maybe in a class or site admin dashboard;anywhere I feel is the best option.. Tried out a few git projects but seems they are not compatible with current django versions..any one offering any idea?!

Answer (score 0):

The Django Admin site is intentionally a separate site, with its own views.

In any app you can make functions that compute various values; but the Admin for that app will need to define its own views, using whatever functions you like.

Comment: It's quite a general answer, so let me try and be a little more specific... Suppose I create view for my model classes, but I know the site is going to be

Comment: ...an admin and designated user only site.. So to save them the hustle of opening new windows to access views, they jhuss acres those views directly in the admin site... I was hoping to get a practical example on this..